# Calculating score of merged string

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the score of two merged lists of names. I need to give one point for each character (including spaces between first and last name) plus one point for each vowel in the name.

```
a = ["John", "Kate", "Oli"]
b = ["Green", "Fletcher", "Nelson"]

vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

gen = ((x, y) for x in a for y in b)

for u, v in gen:
    print u, v
```

I am struggling to figure out what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is desired output here?

Comment: @vishes_shell  Full Name:John Green Score: 13
Full Name:John Fletcher Score: 16
Full Name:John Nelson Score: 14
Full Name:Kate Green Score: 14
Full Name:Kate Fletcher Score: 17
Full Name:Kate Nelson Score: 15
Full Name:Oli Green Score: 13
Full Name:Oli Fletcher Score: 16
Full Name:Oli Nelson Score: 14

Answer (score 1):

So you first `zip` first and last names, then make then `str` with `' '` as separator. And then with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) count how many times so called *vowel* characters occur, `sum` them up, and add `len` of whole name. And that would be `dict` object, then you can do whatever you like with it.

```
from collections import Counter

a = ["John", "Kate", "Oli"]
b = ["Green", "Fletcher", "Nelson"]    
vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

output = {}
for item in [' '.join(i) for i in zip(a,b)]:
    output[item] = sum(Counter(item)[x] for x in vowel) + len(item)
output
```

Output:

```
{'John Green': 13, 'Kate Fletcher': 17, 'Oli Nelson': 13}
```

**UPDATE**

If you need all possible variations of first name and last name you can do that with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter

a = ["John", "Kate", "Oli"]
b = ["Green", "Fletcher", "Nelson"]    
vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

output = {}
for item in [' '.join(i) for i in product(a,b)]:
    output[item] = sum(Counter(item)[x] for x in vowel) + len(item)
output
```

Output:

```
{'John Fletcher': 16,
 'John Green': 13,
 'John Nelson': 14,
 'Kate Fletcher': 17,
 'Kate Green': 14,
 'Kate Nelson': 15,
 'Oli Fletcher': 15,
 'Oli Green': 12,
 'Oli Nelson': 13}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for first, second in gen:
    name = " ".join(first, second)
    score = 0
    for letter in name:
        if letter in vowel:
            score += 1
    score += len(name)
```

It's easier to have them as a string, you can then loop over that string. One point per character is easy, that's just length of the string. If vowel is one extra letter, just loop over letters and if vowel add a point. Voila!